# How to change the colour of a button on load with a text file. [Visual Basic 2010]

Tags: vba, button, colors, text-files

I am designing a seat reservation system using numerous buttons to represent the seats. Details of each seat are stored as single lines on a text file so that each seat corresponds to a specific line in the text file. Within each line of the text file contains either the words 'True' or 'False' to determine the availability of the 'seat'/button.

I am wondering if there was a way for the program to scan the text file as soon as the form has loaded. Then when it finds a line containing 'True', it turns the corresponding button red and changes its enabled state to false.

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("seats.txt")

    For Each b As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()

        If b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat Then
            Select Case b.BackColor
                Case Color.Gold
                    SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = "Gold"
                    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf goldbuttons_click
                Case Color.Silver
                    SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = "Silver"
                    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf silverbuttons_click
                Case Color.DarkOrange
                    SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = "Bronze"
                    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf bronzebuttons_click
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So far I have only been able to make it so that the color changes when I click on a button (The program checks the text file only *after* I click on a button, not when the program starts.)

The below code is similar for goldbuttons_click, silverbuttons_click and bronzebuttons_click.

```
Private Sub goldbuttons_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If lines(Array.IndexOf(Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Reverse.ToArray, sender)).Contains("True") Then
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
        btn.Enabled = False
    Else
    Call Seatscreen()
    SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form loads, you're reading in the contents of the text file:

`lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("seats.txt")`

Simply add a check to see if the word `True` exists in the file:

```
lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("seats.txt")
If Instr(1, lines, "True", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    'Change the button color :
    '
    '

Else:
    'in case you need to do something if True is not found:
    '
    '

End If
```

Note that this will return True if that word is **anywhere** in the file. If you are looking for the word in a specific line, you'll need to use the `.ReadLine` method and specify which line you're looking for